# Access variable declared inside of method in parent class from subclass (swift)

Tags: swift, class, overriding, subclass

I'm fairly certain there is something obvious I am missing and/or doing incorrectly here.

I have a base class with a handleTapped() function that handles a button being tapped on.

In a subclass, I want to override that function but need to access the variables that I declare in the handleTapped() function in the parent class.

Ex:

```
class ParentClass {
  @objc func handleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var a = [Int]()
    var b = 10

    if a[1] == b {
      // do something
    }    
  }
}

class SubClass: ParentClass {
  @objc override func handleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    super.handleTapped(sender: sender)
    if a[1] == b {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't. The subclass has no access to any variables declared in an overridden method. And that's a good thing. Allowing such access would cause untold problems. It's no different than not being able to access private properties of the parent class from a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared in a function cannot be accessed from outside of that scope, including by methods that override their behaviour (unless you use them as a return of that function, which we can't do here).

In this case, you'll need to store the necessary information in the parent class itself, and make sure the access rights are set correctly (internal, or public depending on how your project is set up) so that the Subclass can access and modify that data.

Alternatively, there may be an alternative way to implement this. This might be a candidate where duplication of the code is a more preferable option to exposing data to all subclasses.

Comment: Yeah, I currently just have it duplicated and will probably stick with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take the variables out of the method and into the class like so:

```
class ParentClass {

    var a = [Int]()
    var b = 10

    func handleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if a[1] == b {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

class SubClass: ParentClass {

    override func handleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        super.handleTapped(sender: sender)
        if a[1] == b {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```